# How to run GitLab through Docker on Raspberry Pi 4b on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, docker, git

While trying to start GitLab in a Docker container I am experiencing some issues. The command does works on other pc's. The command consists of:

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname 127.0.0.1 \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

Next, I inspect how gitlab is starting up with command:

```
sudo docker logs -f gitlab
```

Which displays the following error:

> standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error

According to perara in this [link](https://github.com/perara/wg-manager/issues/69) that might be caused to a difference in the architecture of the Raspberry Pi 4b (4gb) and the architecture that is used by `gitlab-ce:latest`. So I tried various other architectures by including the following platform arguments (one per run):

```
--platform /linux/arm/v7
--platform /linux/amd64
--platform /linux/arm64
--platform /linux/armhf
```

which yielded error:

> docker: Error response from deamon: image with reference gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest was found but does not match the specified platform wanted linux/arm64, actual: linux/amd64.

So it seems like I am not finding the right docker image of Gitlab for the right architecture of the Raspberry Pi model 4b with 4Gb. I ran these commands on the Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS  32bit armhf OS.

So I would like to ask, *how could I run GitLab through docker on Ubuntu Server* on a Raspberry Pi 4b (4gb)? E.g. should I use a different Ubuntu Server OS version, and/or specify a different platform argument, and/or get a different source than `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly at the time of this writing GitLab doesn't seem to officially support GitLab-CE on ARM with docker. Their only documented procedure for running CE on ARM is with Debian Buster and GitLabs official package repository.
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/rpi.html

There is a seemingly popular 3rd party build of CE for Docker ARM but it's only for arm64, so you'd need to run a 64bit distro.
https://hub.docker.com/r/yrzr/gitlab-ce-arm64v8
https://git.yrzr.tk/docker/gitlab-ce-arm64

To switch to using the 3rd party images you'll need to run a 64bit distro and should only need to replace

```
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

with

```
yrzr/gitlab-ce-arm64v8:latest
```

in your run command

Comment: Thanks! +1 Still... gitlab does not work on raspberry pi in 2023. Using this method helped

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want to rely on third party pre-built images,
here's a little project that allows building your own GitLab image for Raspberry Pi 4, that is using official GitLab Dockerfile and debian package for RPI:
https://github.com/xaxa06/gitlab-rpi-docker